# Subquery working fine but when using update weired results are coming

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
updaTE person.PersonPhone set PhoneNumber=Replace(PhoneNumber,Right(PhoneNumber,2),'90') 
where PhoneNumber IN
(SELECT Top (3) PhoneNumber from person.PersonPhone
where PhoneNumber like '%89')
```

Select top 3 works fine but when i use this with update around 104 records are updated. Total records ending with 89 were 200 but 104 records were updated.

Comment: MySql database i am using

Comment: add MySQL as a tag to your question... always indicate which dbms

Comment: Why do you use `top 3` in the subquery. Even if there are 200 records ending with 89. Are you sure the number of records with the top 3 numbers equals 200? I guess it equals 104. And that's what you are getting it here.

Comment: How do you expect the top(3) inside a subquery to limit the number of row of the outer query AND change the very column you are comparing to as well? the top(3) only applies inside that subquery, and you should always have an order by when using top. Finally how could we know what data you have in those tables? You would need to share some sample data too.

Comment: I executed my subquery seprately to know no of records it shows 200. I need to update only 3 records out of those 200 records.

Comment: Top is sqlserver and person.PersonPhone is a table in adventureworks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the update to a select to see what rows you are getting due to the IN clause. Note that duplicate phone numbers would result in the "IN TOP (3)" returning more than 3 records.